# Android Emulator Power Key Long Press Event

Tags: android, keyevent

I want to add item in the context menu of Power options, appear after long key press of Power.
I have tried to capture event onkeyLongpress but its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hook into the Power button in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Event for power key won't be delivered to other child window, as it is intercepted in `PhoneWindowManager.java`

You can add your option in **GlobalActions.java**

```
private ArrayList<Action> mItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add item in the context menu of Power options

That is not possible except via firmware modifications, AFAIK.

Comment: I want to know what is the reason. Its also a key. So why we cannot capture key event or context menu? Please give me relative detail.