# override power button callback

Tags: android, callback

Is it possible in an acitvity override the callback called when the power button is pressed? My target is to prevent the screen off.

I found this - [How to hook into the Power button in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android) -but it seems don't work.

THX

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the screen on with a wake lock:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

But you should be carefull with it because it really drains the battery.