# Detect on/off Key Press Android

Tags: java, android, listener, keylistener

How can I detect the power button or lock screen button being pressed? When my game is paused in this way, it can cause the game to crash because I need to pause a thread when it happens.

Comment: Chances are your problem is better solved by correctly implementing the activity lifecycle, in particular taking the appropriate actions in response to the various messages.

Comment: You should not be looking for key presses to fix your app.  The Android lifecycle is a much better choice, and should solve the issue of pausing your game when the user exits or pauses it.  Have you tried overriding `onPause` in your game's `Activity`?

Comment: I have done this, but I think I am handling my threads incorrectly at the moment. I will have to go back and maybe try managing them in different methods, and then write the code for handling the lockscreen issue in the onPause method

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From Christian's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // do what you want with the power button
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

However Jake Basile is right.  Unless you have a really good reason for doing something special when the Power Button is pressed, you should be using standard Android life-cycle functions.

When the Power Button is pressed it will call the onPause() method of your application, and when you unlock the device it will call onResume().  This is where you should be managing your thread to prevent the app from crashing.

The [documentation on Activity's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) will give you a detailed description of life-cycle functions, when they are called, and how you should use them.
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In KitKat I just noticed that clicking Power Button now calls onStop() !!! this is a big change, never used to be like this.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`onPause`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) and [`onResume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) methods. These are called when your app is no longer in the foreground (when a lock screen comes up) or when the phone is put to sleep, and when your app is brought back to the foreground.

This is the standard process for the Activity life cycle in Android, that is more fully documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: I had a feeling this was going to be how to do it. The only problem is right now I am already using these methods to kill my threads and bring the game screen back to the menu when the user wants to quit the game... So that must be why the game is crashing completely when this button is pressed... Hmmm might have to handle things differently.

Comment: You could try moving them to `onStart` and/or `onStop`, and see what happens. It might need to be earlier or later in the lifecycle to avoid thread issues.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, having multiple threads running always seems to get fussy... I would accept your answer but the other answer here seems to answer the question I was asking even though I realize I should be implementing my thread management using Android activity lifecycle methods differently...

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the answers to this question ignore the fact that when writing an app, it is important to know which event caused a particular standard Android life cycle function to be called.  There is a onBackPressed() function; why not have an onPowerPressed() and onHomePressed() as well?  Apps often need to do different things in the standard life cycle functions depending upon which event caused them to be called.  Right now it is a real pain to figure out whether a standard life cycle method was called as a result of a home button press or a power button press.

Answer (score 1):

To detect whether an Android app is starting or stopping, you can use these rules ([reference](http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2015/06/05/detecting-whether-an-android-app-is-stopping-or-starting/)):

- When the user is entering, onResume is always called (on the activity that will be current)
- When the user is leaving, onStop is always called (on the current activity), except when pressing the power button (to turn off) where you *may* only see an onPause call.
- When the user is moving between activities, onResume is always called on the new activity, and onStop is always called on the old one. The onResume call is always before onStop

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre did you feel the link I included was unhelpful?  It provides the evidence behind the answer I gave, and more detail so I hoped it was helpful.

Comment: I removed it because links at the end of answers (specially to a blog) are considered borderline spam

Answer (score 0):

Override the life cycle methods. The solution for detecting the pressing of the power button that was chosen as the answer is no longer allowed in Android ()