# Prevent Android activity from being recreated on turning screen off

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, lifecycle, lifetime, activity-lifecycle

How to prevent an activity from being recreated on turning screen off?

**What I do**

> 1. Start Bejewels and go to the jewelry screen.
> 2. Press power button shortly. The screen is turned off, but the device is not.
> 3. Press power button again.

**What I see**

> The same screen as before turning screen off.

In case of my application (trivial one, just a web-app with a single WebView) the scenario is the following:

**What I do**

> 1. Start my app. The activity onCreate() method loads an URL into the WebView.
> 2. Press power button shortly. The screen is turned off, but the device is not.
> 3. Press power button again.

**What I see**

> The WebView is reloading the page.

**What I expected**

> As in Bejewels case I want to see the same screen, that for my app is the page in its previous state: scripts are running, a form fields are
>   filled etc.

Debugging showed, that I was wrong (in a previous question) and onDestroy() and onCreate() are being called one-by-one when the screen is just turned on. And since I still hear a music, played by a script, when the screen is off, it looks like both the activity and the WebView do exist until I press power button again.

What I tried.

1. android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" The same behavior.
2. Reading about intents (to no avail, I just did not understand, how they are applied to my situation).
3. Using PhoneGap. It behaves differently: just kills the whole application on pressing power button. This IS better, but not the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the view in Application.onCreate().
2. Add the view to a layout in Activity.onCreate().
3. Remove the view from the layout in Activity.onDestroy().

Details are here:
[Attach/detach Android view to/from layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505346/attach-detach-android-view-to-from-layout)

Answer (score 29):

The solution to this problem may be the same as that described here: [onDestroy gets called each time the screen goes on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772988/ondestroy-gets-called-each-time-the-screen-goes-on)

It sounds like your activity is being restarted due to configuration changes, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html. The most common is when your app is in landscape mode (like most games) and then the screen lock is engaged by tapping the power button. The screen-lock is in portrait mode and therefore triggers a change in orientation which triggers the activity to be restarted.

This behaviour can be overridden by adding:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

... to your manifest file if you are targeting API level less than 13. Or

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

... if you are targeting API level greater than 13.

Note you may need to go project->properties and update your project build target. 'screenSize' will not be recognised if your build target is less than 13.

It may be a different configuration change that is causing the activity to be reset. The following link provides a list of the possible configuration changes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to the activity part in the manifest xml.
see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Nothing has changed. (I didn't remove android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true").

Comment: after pressing power button to screen off and then again to screen on the onResume() is called, what are you doing in onResume()?

Comment: 1. Yes, onResume() is called. I've checked it (overridden and called Toast). 2. Sorry for being dumb, I just didn't guess I had to do something in onResume(). So, it was not overridden and now it contains just Toast call. 3. Behavior now is the following: after pressing the button first time, when screen is off, the page is reloading in background (the music stops to play then plays from start, there is a javascript in onload section of web page that starts music playing).