# Application class recreated each time the screen goes on

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

The steps that explains the problem I faced are below;
**1.** I start the android application.
**2.** I put it on backgorund by pressing home button.
**3.** I turn the screen off.
**4.** I turn the screen on after some seconds.
**5.** My application suddenly becomes foreground. I realised that the application is forced to start again and the application class that I used is created again and then the start page of my application (*this is login page*) is shown although what page is opened before the step 2.

**What I have tried so far is below;**
I put configChanges and screenOrientation in all the activiy tags in my Androidmanifest.xml (I tried to put them one by one and both together also.)

```
 <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:name="com.myproject.Activity"
                android:screenOrientation="nosensor"/>
```

I also tried to use screenOrientation="portrait" but didn't work.

My problem is related with the [How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1512045/1351327), [Prevent Android activity from being recreated on turning screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10498636/1351327) and like others, but I could not find the solution of my problem yet.

Can you please help?

Edit 1: ******************************** 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <!-- Permission to use NFC -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

    <permission android:name="com.myproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.myproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <!--
        Add this permission to check which network access properties (e.g.
        active type: 3G/WiFi).
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Add this permission to access WLAN MAC address. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!-- Add this permission to access HW ID. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:name="com.myproject.hce.MyApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
        >

        <!-- Splash Activity -->
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Login Activity -->

        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:name="com.myproject.LoginView"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:name="com.myproject.MainView"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
            android:value="12h3g21h4v32hv43hv4" />

        <service
            android:name="com.myproject.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.myproject.hce.McbpHceService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.myproject.pushnotifications.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.myproject.hce.MyService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Application class**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication MyApplication;

    private MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks;

    public static MyApplication getMyApplication() {
        return MyApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { //coko1

        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, "MyApplication " + "onCreate ...");

        if (MyApplication == null)
            MyApplication = this;
        else
            return;

        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, "MyApplication " + "super.onCreate() ...");

        super.onCreate();

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyLifecycleHandler());

        setMyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks());

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(getMyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks());
    }

    public MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks getMyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks() {
        return MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks;
    }

    public void setMyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks(
            MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks) {
        this.MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks = MyActivityLifeCycleCallbacks;
    }
}
```

Edit 2:**************** 
**Splash.java**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    public static Context context;

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Splash ";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "onCreate...");

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this)); // catch unexpected error
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        context = this;

        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "MainView starts...");
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainView.class);
        Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        Splash.this.finish();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "onResume ...");
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**MainView.class**

```
public class MainView extends Activity {


    Context context;
    String LOG_TAG = "MainView ";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "onCreate ...");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
        context = this;

        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "LoginView starts...");
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, LoginView.class);
        Splash.this.startActivity(loginIntent);
        Splash.this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "onResume ...");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "onStart ...");
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "onPause ...");
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        MyLog.i(UtilConstants.LOG_TAG_HCE, LOG_TAG + "onDestroy ...");
        super.onDestroy();
    };
}
```

Edit 3:**************** 
I use fragments, maybe this will be the reason, but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you talking about `Application` or `Activity`?

Comment: Can we get the code of the launched Activity ?

Comment: Application class. And as a result of the re-creating the Application class, the last Activity is destroyed and the login activity that is the beginning activity of the application is created and shown again.

Comment: Added some code (AndroidManfest.xml and Application class)

Comment: Added other activity codes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to a library I used. It works in background and makes the application restarts. 
I suspend it when the application goes to background and resume it when it comes foregorund. That is it, the problem is solved.
Thanks you anyway.