# Android app fragments in viewpager become detached for no apparent reason

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm writing an android application that uses a `ViewPager` to contain 3 screens that can be accessed via swiping left and right. These tabs are defined as fragment subclasses with separate XML files. It works, but for some reason whenever I unplug my device or connect/disconnect a bluetooth input device (possibly other things but these are the main causes I've seen) the fragments become detached, and the screen goes white, then the app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.samboycoding.<snip>/me.samboycoding.<snip>.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08006d (me.samboycoding.<snip>:id/pager) for fragment TabDeviceOverview{d0b5892 #0 id=0x7f08006d android:switcher:2131230829:0}
```

I've got no idea why this happens. I've tried setting `setRetainInstance` to true, and I've also tried using the fragment manager to store my fragment, but to no avail. Firstly, is there no way to ensure a fragment is kept loaded - as I think that's what's happening here, and secondly if not, how do I go about detecting this state and recreating the view?

I can post code if desired, just tell me what to post.

Adapter class: https://hastebin.com/zayewipimo.java

Relevant part of my onCreate: https://hastebin.com/gubikixude.java

Comment: post your activity and viewpager adapter code...

Comment: What specific part of the activity? I'm not posting the full thing, as there's some code I don't want to share, and it's over 400 lines anyway.

Comment: related to the viewpager and adapter initialization...adding fragment...to the viewpager

Comment: Both posted, see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) remove this line:

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

it will cause fragments to retain it's view rather than recreating it's view.

2) change in your adapter class:

extends the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` class

```
PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

3) overide the `getItemPosition()` in your adapter class and make it return `POSITION_NONE`.

```
  @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I still get the exact same error.

Comment: post the error logcat..and `clean build-->Run` the apk

Comment: I'll clean build it first, then post a logcat if it fails again.

Comment: Yup. Still fails. Here's a full stack: https://hastebin.com/raw/anobotugix

Comment: Sorry if you're still looking at this, but I just realised I didn't mention you in that last comment and I can't seem to edit it, so... @rafsanahmad007

Comment: in your activity `if (!initComplete)`..is this condition works when app goes in `onPause()` or connected to Bluetooth..?

Comment: No. `initComplete` is set to true when `onPostInit` in the activity finishes for the first time to prevent the entire application from being recreated should it be suspended. Is it this that's causing the issue, and if so how can I prevent data being lost when the app is suspended, because currently the entire activity is re-created without this statement.

Comment: i am not sure exactly this causes the error...but you can try remove it and re run the application..also to prevent recreating the activity take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498636/prevent-android-activity-from-being-recreated-on-turning-screen-off

Comment: This seems to work, but I have no idea why. I guess i'll just workaround. Thanks for your help.

Comment: happy to help...you are welcome to accept the answer if it helps. Thanks