# OnPause and OnStop() called immediately after starting activity

Tags: android, android-activity, wakelock, activity-lifecycle

I have an activity that needs to turn screen on(if offed) when it is started.
So in onCreate, I have:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Using this with help of wakelock in broadcasr receiver , I am able to cause my activity to display whenever it is started from broadcast receiver.

But problem is very strange, activity lifecycle calls in this manner, onPause() and onResume immediately after starting activity

1. onCreate
2. onStart
3. onResume
4. onPause
5. onStop
6. onStart
7. onResume

---

So the problem is on start and on resume calling twice, with on stop also calling, I want to implement some logic in onStop() but, with such behavior app will not work correctly.

**Edit**

I found problem is only due to flag FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED. and when device is locked. and it only happens when device is locked before activity is starting.

P.S I am using alarm manager with broadcast receiver, and then starts activity from broadcast receiver.

Comment: amazing question, i have this also with the same flag `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`, voted up

Comment: I solved it by using a little delay in a handler, that checks in onStop

Comment: @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();

  if (isDeviceSleeping) {
   if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 2000) {
    return;
   }
  }

Comment: this could be one way but not proper solution

Comment: This answer saved me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14053686/5247630
it's about detecting if the screen is ON

Comment: Did yours work? I am having the same trouble, though I have used wake lock and disable keyguard, it shows the keypad and pauses my activity

Answer (score 52, accepted):

- **Let us understand why the lifecycle methods are called multiple times.**

Here is an important code comment documented in [ActivityThread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java?av=f#2242), which is responsible for executing the activities of the application process.

> We accomplish this by going through the normal startup (because
>   activities expect to go through onResume() the first time they run,
>   before their window is displayed), and then pausing it.

Right after `onResume`, the activity window is attached to the window manager and `onAttachedtoWindow` is invoked. If the screen is on, the activity window will get focus and `onWindowFocusChanged` is invoked with `true` parameter. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()):

> Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your
>   activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard
>   may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain
>   that your activity is visible to the user

In the reported issue, the screen if off. Hence activity window will not get focus, which results in activity's `onPause` method getting called followed by `onStop` method, as the activity window is not visible.

Since `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` flag is set on activity window, the window manager service turns on the screen using power manager api. Following is the [WindowManagerService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService.java?av=f#2755) code:

```
public int relayoutWindow(...) {
    ...
    toBeDisplayed = !win.isVisibleLw();
    ...
    if (toBeDisplayed) {
        ...
        if ((win.mAttrs.flags
            & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON) != 0) {
            if (DEBUG_VISIBILITY) Slog.v(TAG,
                "Relayout window turning screen on: " + win);
                win.mTurnOnScreen = true;
            }
        ...
        if (mTurnOnScreen) {
            if (DEBUG_VISIBILITY) Slog.v(TAG, "Turning screen on after layout!");
            mPowerManager.wakeUp(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
            mTurnOnScreen = false;
        }
        ...
}
```

After the screen turns on `onStart` and `onPause` are called again.

Hence : `onCreate - onStart - onResume - onPause - onStop - onStart - onPause`.

This can be verified by locking the device and starting the activity using `adb` command or `eclipse`.

- **Ideal Solution**

If you start a task in `onCreate` you need to stop it in `onDestory` (if the task is still pending). Similarly for `onStart` it would be `onStop` and for `onResume` it would be `onPause`.

- **Workaround**

If you can't follow the above protocol, you can check the status of activity window focus using [hasWindowFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#hasWindowFocus()) in `onPause` method. Normally the activity window focus status will be true in `onPause`. In scenarios like screen is off or screen is on with keyguard displayed, the activity window focus will be false in `onPause`.

```
boolean mFocusDuringOnPause;

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause;

    mFocusDuringOnPause = hasWindowFocus();    
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(mFocusDuringOnPause) {
        // normal scenario
    } else {
        // activity was started when screen was off / screen was on with keygaurd displayed
    }
}
```

Comment: Good explanation, but work around is not working, I would rather like to set a flag value in onWindowFocusChanged, and then do handle onPause() and onStop() after window in being focussed

Comment: Why doesn't your workaround use `onWindowFocusChanged`? On it's surface, that event sounds perfect.

Comment: Just to add onRestart also gets called after onStop. If anybody is doing some logic inside onStart, just check if activity got restarted, then avoid running logic again in onStart

Comment: what about onResume/onStart called multiple times, what's the solution?

Comment: tried with Android 14, `hasWindowFocus` is always false when you open activity from the notification from the lock screen

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to you `Activity` in your `Manifest`. This may solve your problem.

Comment: How will that solve the problem? Listening for config changes will just prevent the activity from handling the changes automatically. It has nothing to do with screen on/off scenario described

Answer (score 2):

The workaround by Manish Mulimani worked for me, except I first check for the window focus and then call through to the super.onPause():

```
public void onPause() {
    mFocusDuringOnPause = hasWindowFocus();    
    super.onPause();
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mFocusDuringOnPause) {
        // normal scenario
    } else {
        // activity was started when screen was off or screen was on with keyguard displayed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to implement some logic in onStop() but with such behavior app will not work correctly. you didn’t show us what exactly you have inside onStop() but I think your logic probably restarts the activity..
 in that case  you Can implement your logic in onStop like that:

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

         //implement your code only if !STATE_OFF - to prevent infinite loop onResume <-> onStop  while screen is off                      
        DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        for (Display display : dm.getDisplays()){
               if(display.getState() != Display.STATE_OFF){

                 //implement your code only if device is not in "locked"  state     
                KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                if( !myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())      
                    //If needed you can call finish() (call onDestroy()) and your logic will restart your activity only once.             
                    finish();                  
                    // implement your logic here (your logic probably restarts the activity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2. other solution that may help you will be to avoid onStop() and use onWindowFocusChanged with bool hasFocus

   ```
     /**
     * Called when the current {@link Window} of the activity gains or loses
     * focus.  This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible
     * to the user.
     */
       @Override
          public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            if( ! hasFocus  ){
            }
            else{
            }
          }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed there is `activity` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml` called `android:showOnLockScreen="true|false"`

for example:

```
   <activity android:name="AlarmAlertFullScreen"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:theme="@style/AlarmAlertFullScreenTheme"
                android:showOnLockScreen="true"
                android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/>
```

I searched the web for its documentation but no luck, but from its name it should work as the Window flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` do.

---

the only document I've found

> Specify that an Activity should be shown over the lock screen and, in
>   a multiuser   environment, across all users' windows [boolean]

---

**Edit**

can you please try to call your flag code before calling `super.onCreate(...)`

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    this.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        //then call super
        super.onCreate(bundle);
.
.
.
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the reason behind this, is the key-guard screen is stopping the activity at first time, then the activity is resumed again

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have used this and it works fine

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        _wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
            POWER_SERVICE);
    _wakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated

Answer (score -1):

Use WakeLocker class. It have methods to wake screen on