# Activity's onStart() and onResume() methods called twice when start activity from lock screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-pendingintent

I create a notification with PendingIntent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notifId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Starting the SimpleActivity by clicking on this notification on locked screen causes the next activity's lifecycle: `onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume() -> onPause() -> onStop() -> onStart() -> onResume()` or sometimes `onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume() -> onPause() -> onResume()`. But when I start SimpleActivity by clicking on notification from unlocked screen then it works fine.

I found some solution in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25474853/4800960). But it doesn't works for case when activity has a fragments. I found that in some devices in such case fragments may replicate theirs activity's lifecycle so onStart() also called twice in fragments too.

Is this a normal behavior? And is there a way to avoid this so Activity's lifecycle will look like this `onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume()`?

Comment: can you check the same with this sample from https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/Notifications

Comment: @Radhunandan same

Comment: There is no guarantee that `onResume()` will only be called once in this scenario. Your app must be resilient to this behaviour and respond accordingly.

Comment: @IvanKononov did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673014/opening-app-from-foreground-services-notification-on-the-lock-screen-causes-act

Comment: @DavidWasser what about `onStart/onStop`, why are they called double times only when notification was clicked  form lock screen? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673014/opening-app-from-foreground-services-notification-on-the-lock-screen-causes-act