# Android activity onDestroy() called on screen lock

Tags: android, android-activity

**onDestroy** function in my activity class gets called when screen sleeps or if screen is locked. I know this should not happen as the flow of control is supposed to be onPause()->onStop(). On locking screen the flow of control is like this: **onPause()->onStop()->onDestroy()**. I have given `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in my android manifest as suggested by answers to similar questions but that did not work. isFinishing() function returns false when checked from onStop().

Can anyone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: have you ended the activity in onpause?

Comment: What is the android version on the device that you test on?

Comment: Are you setting any other attributes for the activity in AndroidManifest like noHistory

Comment: another thing.. in the current devices there is a deveeloper option "stop activity when background".. have you checked that?

Comment: @Anirudh I tried setting android:noHistory:"false" but that did not help

Comment: @Siddharth This issue was found in android version 4.2.2

Comment: @StinePike no I have not ended my activity at onPause and I have not set that developer option and other apps work fine on the same device.

Comment: Well setting noHistory to false will result in this behaviour. From your comments, it look you don't have it set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem here:

[Activity Lifecycle X Power Button X Lock Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948315/activity-lifecycle-x-power-button-x-lock-screen)

The solution was to add the configChanges like you did, but you are missing the **screenSize** type:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: There is no screenSize option for configChanges android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenLayout" is what I did

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Comment: That's weird, because the documentation says that it was added on API Level 13: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config, so add it manually and test if it works!

Comment: Try to clean the project and clean the link markers, this shouldn't be an error as your target is 17 and this flag was added on 14.

Comment: I have the same issue and am targeting SDK version 11, so I can't use screenSize.