# Preventing from onDestroy being called screen off button pressed

Tags: android

I have Activity that gets populated with info. When I press the screen off button and come back to the Activity, the info is not there anymore.

Btw, If I use the home button the info doesn't disappear. On logs, it shows it doesn't call onDestroy;

Therefore, onDestroy discards the info. I don't want onDestroy. HOw could I  make that happen.

Thanks.

Comment: how about doing the displaying job in `onResume()` rather than `onCreate()`

Comment: To make it more clear post your code of activity.

Comment: What happens if someone rotates the screen, or attaches an external keyboard? These, and other events, will also call the `Activity` lifecycle methods. It would be better to store any information you want to keep in some way (i.e. in [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState))

Answer (score 1):

OnDestroy will always be called. You should save data and than recreate Activity on onCreate. Everything is nicely explained [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Read section "Saving Persistent State". Also read about lifecycle of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save activity's info on **onSaveInstanceState()** and restore the state on **onRestoreInstanceState()**.
This approach also helps you also in configuration changes state.
**onSaveInstanceState()** is called before destroying activity and **onRestoreInstanceState()** is called just before recreating the activity.
Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably duplicate of [Android activity onDestroy() called on screen lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771319/android-activity-ondestroy-called-on-screen-lock).

This behaviour usually occurs at landscape orientation activities. Add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml activity tag.