# How to handle power button (Android)

Tags: android, andengine

I am a developing game using andengine. When I press the power button, the `onPause()` method is not being called. How do I fix the issue?

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {      
    //this method is not calling when press power button 
    super.onPause(); 
    this.mEngine.onPause() ;
}
```

Comment: do you know what else it could be calling instead of onPause?

Comment: why it should be called immediately after power button press?

Comment: @supriya it should work. Print some log there.

Comment: @sandrstar because it should :)

Comment: You are pressing to turn the screen off, not pressing long enough to power off?  Might sound stupid, but just asking....

Comment: turning screen off should call `onPause()`. power off, should destroy activity. (effectivly also doing `onPause()` before `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 2):

Weird, haven't heard of it **not** being called. Let me research a bit.

Okay, pressing power should **always** call `onPause()`, there seem to be some kind of bug in your code. Could you add some log calls to follow every step. and print the DDMS log.

**Other possible problems:**

It seems some devices misbehave and call `onPause()` twice when pressing the power button.

In this case try using the powerManager to see if the screen is actually turned of.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isScreenOn()) {
   //now do stuff
}
```

Maybe `onPause()` is called but `onCreate()` is called right after ?

When you turn off the device, the lock screen is displayed.  This typically forces the display to a particular orientation.  If the screen is not currently in that orientation, it will need to be changed, and the top activity's configuration appropriately changed to match.

You can add config changes like this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screensize"
```

To make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure why it should. Would appreciate any reference to the documentation. I thought that sometimes on some devices lock button might be pressed by ancident and so it might be reasonable to keep activity for some seconds.

Comment: When the Power Button is pressed it will call the onPause() method of your application, and when you unlock the device it will call onResume(). This is how the Android Activity lifecycle is being managed by android O/S

Comment: If an activity in the foreground of the screen (at the top of the stack), it is active or running. If you press power, your home screen has takken focus of your activity, and turning your screen off.  If an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your activity), it is paused. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848518/detect-on-off-key-press-android

Comment: This is how it should behave unless phone settings can change power behavior making it do absolutely do nothing. But power button always  makes your activity lose focus. making at **least** call onPause() because the activity will follow its state path. And is in the documentation I provided.

Comment: Yeah, it looks logical (and documentation provides explanation about loosing focus), however documentation still allow phone manufacturers not to start home by pressing power or introduce delays for its starting. Just wondering if it's implemented on any phone that way.

Comment: True but any other action except _nothing_ still loses focus on current activity. Thus calling `onPause()`.  The only way to go around this is to make sure the power button does not work, and does nothing. Which i doubt any manufacturer will do.