# Is it possible on Android to send SMS, Email and make a Phone Call on pressing the start button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-hardware

Is it technically feasible to do the following in Android on pressing the phone start button. Lets say the user's phone is off. When the user presses the on button, then the following happens:

1. Send SMS
2. Send Email
3. Make Call

Currently, I tried to find the **KeyCode** of the phone's START BUTTON but unable to get any response in the log cat.

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;

        @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {


            Log.e("KeyCode", "KeyCode:" + keyCode);
            Log.e("KeyEvent", "KeyEvent" + event);

            return true;

    }
```

Looking forward to a credible answer with precise technical details. Thanks

Comment: What have you done? Did you do any research?

Comment: Is your application running when power key is pressed?

Comment: My application runs fine but I am unable to retrieve the KeyCode of the start button in logcat. Although other KeyCodes are retrievable.

Comment: @user1281750 Check the update in my question please. Thanks

Comment: @Niko My app loads fine but when i press the start button, then my phone gets locked. And then i have to unlock the phone to go to my app.

Comment: Its done now. The KeyCode on HTC is 26. Just one last thing: Is 26 a universal KeyCode on every android powered smartphone? Thanks

Comment: @Niko@user1281750 There are 2 scenarios here: 1. I just press the start button (the phone gets locked with offscreen). 2. I keep my finger while pressing the on/off button (the phone asks the user to turn it off or restart it). I want to catch the keycode in both scenarios. Currently, I am now able to catch the keycode in scenario 2 only.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman I have answered to your question. It will help you

Comment: @TGMCians Great! Can you please check my comment in your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Register the Broadcast Receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml. This receiver broadcast when screen went ON. This execute either your application activity is on screen or not.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyBroadCastReciever.java

```
public class MyBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i("Check","Screen went ON");
            Toast.makeText(context, "screen ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Here you can write the logic of send SMS, Email, Make a call

        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

> Logic to make the call

You can do this simply. It make the call directly.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number")); 
startActivity(callIntent);
```

and add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

> Logic to send the SMS

You can do this simply. This send the SMS

```
public void sendSMS() {
    String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
    String message = "Hello World!";

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

and add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

> Logic to send the Email

If you want to send the Email here without any user interaction on id then either design the PHP web service and call the web service in the android application.

If you want to send the mail from the configured email then you can use the `Intent`.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Note : If you want to perform this action in Activity then register the broadcast receiver in the Activity and unregister when activity destroy.

Comment: Can you please post the the entire project code. That'll be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
          {


     // do watever you want here

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: You are right. There are 2 scenarios here: 1. I just press the start button (the phone gets locked with offscreen). 2. I keep my finger while pressing the on/off button (the phone asks the user to turn it off or restart it). I want to catch the keycode in both scenarios.

Comment: so what is the problem with this? you are not able to give conditions..let me know...

Comment: Yes exactly...that's the problem. I am not able to give conditions in order to make the app sense whether 1. I have just pressed the on/off button or 2. I have pressed it longer to turn it off or restart it.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying

> Lets say the user's phone is off.

So I asume the phone is completly off and you want to do those things on boot. I would create a receiver StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver.

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //Do whatever you want to do on boot.
        }
    }
}
```

And place this in your minifest

```
    receiver
        android:name="yourpackage.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can never get `StartButton` events in your application's

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
}
```

Because android system don't dispatch this event for us. But if your intension is to do some task on completion of Phone's booting, you have to listen to `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` `Broadcast` & registation have to be done through `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

These two posts have all the information you need:

[Listen to volume buttons in background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154118/listen-to-volume-buttons-in-background-service)

[Detect on/off Key Press Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848518/detect-on-off-key-press-android)

Basically your application needs to be running to detect key events.

`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER` is the key for on/off button

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do in this way

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
              // Your code here
              return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

visit also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this answer by Dave Webb:[Broadcast reciever on shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190126/is-there-any-way-to-receive-a-notification-of-when-a-user-powers-off-his-her-and/2190184#2190184)

He writes:

You can use the [ACTION_SHUTDOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) Intent which is broadcast when the phone is about to shutdown. The documentation says:

> Apps will not normally need to handle this, since the foreground
>   activity will be paused as well.
>
> In other words, if you respond to all the lifecycle events for your
>   Activity appropriately, there's no need to use this unless you really
>   want to do something specific related to shutdown.
>
> The ACTION_SHUTDOWN Intent was introduced in API Level 4, in other
>   words it'll only be sent on phones running Android 1.6 or later.

You'll trap the Broadcast with a BroadcastReceiver. It will look something like this:

```
public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Insert code here
    }

}
```

You'll also need an entry in your Manifest like the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">   
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Depending on what you're doing, another option would be to use the [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) Intent which is sent when the phone is restarted.

I hope it will help!