# How to capture app switch key using onKeyDown in Android?

Tags: android, onkeydown

I am trying to capture app switch key and home key on android 3.1 and 4.0 but it doesn't seem like its working.

here is what I am doing

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
   if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    { 
        Log.d ("onkeydown","app switch key");
    }
   else if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE.KEYCODE_HOME && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    { 
        Log.d ("onkeydown","home key");
    }
    //EDIT:
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

My log.d statement is not printed. Is it possible to capture these 2 keys?

updated code with correct return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um.

Well, no, you can't.

> public static final int KEYCODE_HOME
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Key code constant: Home key.
>
> **This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: how about KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH. Why this one is not captured?

Comment: I would *assume* that the Home Activity or the OS framework have trapped that key, and you cannot receive the event. It would rather defeat the purpose of having such a key, after all.

Comment: Its annoying...onkeydown is not even called with app_switch is pressed :(

Answer (score 1):

**It can be achieved using reflection.**

It is under class `android.os.ServiceManager` having an aidl `com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarService` and it contains `toggleRecentApps` method

And also try this [method here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956263/3496570)

Answer (score 0):

The **super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)** is missing, i think you should try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

   if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    { 
        Log.d ("onkeydown","app switch key");
    }
   else if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE.KEYCODE_HOME && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    { 
        Log.d ("onkeydown","home key");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Doing the same using switch statement:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        switch(keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
             Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, "Pressed Camera Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
             Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, "Pressed 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
             Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, "Pressed Home Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
             Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, "Pressed Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event). Same result. Here is something interesting when I am pressing app switch key onkeydown is not invoked. I have a breakpoint...hmm

Comment: Can you provide more sample code, you may be missing thing, i guess.

Comment: No I just updated original post with correct return statement...that is my sample code