# Reference android.R.id.home on pre 3.0 devices

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is there an easy way to get a reference to the home button on devices running less then 3.0?

I can do findViewById(android.R.id.home) on 3.0 and later but that fails to work on older devices. I don't need to listen for clicks, I just need its location to position another view.

For clarification I'm referring to this view: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

Comment: The HOME button on my HTC Desire (running Android v2.2) is a physical button - you're not going to be able to find it's location with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing... but it sounds hacky :)

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home)
```

Comment: Thanks! Basically I want to pass it as a view to this guy https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView. Users who beta tested my app were not familier with android paradigms. I'm assuming they were on older devices so with ABS backport they have not been "educated" yet.

Answer (score -1):

You probably shouldn't override the default behaviour of the home button, however take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android/8883447#8883447) and see if it helps.