# How to catch HomeKeyPress event in Android?

Tags: android, events

I want to handle the `homekeypress` event in my Android app and have tried with some codes but failed. Some are saying that there is no such method or Android gives `no-longer support` of that sort of events even if they were exist. Is there any way to handle that `event`?

Comment: There is no way to intercept that key event, but you can use you activity's `onPause` method to detect when the activity is hidden.

Comment: check this out : [Detect home button press][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android

Comment: no you can't. but you can look at `onUserLeaveHint` which may help you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()