# Want to do several things if user presses home button

Tags: android

I want to do several things if the user press home button,my code does not work.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click Home ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect home button press in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to detect the home button press action inside an application. The reason for doing so is to prevent malicious apps that cannot be exited.

**Source:** [Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android)

Comment: It is possible in some case. See my comment above.