# detecting when my application is leaving to the background

Tags: android, lifecycle

I am developing an application which request user to enter passcode whenever he/she leave the application or Press home button. This will be applied on all the application activities.
i have tried the Activity lifecycle 
onResume,onRestart and so on. but those will be called when moving from one activity to another activity. 
i have tried also this code

```
@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint() {
    long uiDelta = (System.currentTimeMillis() - userInteractionTime);

    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    Log.i("bThere","Last User Interaction = "+uiLag);
    if (uiDelta < 100)
        Log.i("appname","Home Key Pressed");    
    else
        Log.i("appname","We are leaving, but will probably be back shortly!");
```

But, this will be called when switching between activities not only when pressing home button.

Any idea on how I can detect leaving the application ?

Comment: try using onWindowFocusChanged and onStop methods . more can be found here -> http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

Comment: @shaydel I tried it but it is the same. when i move to another activity by Intent it will give me that the application is in the background.

Comment: i must not understood you, you seem to find that your app is on the background , when another app is in front , what is missing?

Comment: try `HomeWatcher`  as @Jack suggests in the following post  -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/27956263/1119365

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your app is in background or not

1 -  you should include   android.permission.GET_TASKS in your AndroidManifest.xml

2 -Put this code in you Application class.

```
public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
      ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
      if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an extra boolean on intents that execute the flow between your activities indicating that the passcode request should not be requested. then on your activities `onResume` you consume this boolean once and flip it to false, so that next time the activitry is resumed the passcode will be requested again. this should work i think. please let us know if it did :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the history when the User switches between Activities. So He Cant use the backbutton.

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar issue when i want to disconnect chat server connection when the app is no longer used or in background mode. In iOS there is a method

```
 didEnterInBackground()
```

which is used to detect when the app is in background or not. I was looking for similar behaviour in android but ended up using workaround to solve .

So what did solve the solution to my prob is , i add timer on every activity's onPause and onResume . Start timer on host activity's onPause and stop on going timer on target activity's onResume. So if there is no target activity ( app in background or another app come in ) , it would automatically disconnect the chat server.

```
  timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            disconnectChatServer();
        }
    },1000);
```

You can adjust delay which in millisecond .

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* 
* @param context
* @return 
*/
public static boolean isBackground(Context context) {    
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
        if (appProcess.processName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND) {
                Log.i(String.format("Background App:", appProcess.processName));
                return true;
             }else{
                Log.i(String.format("Foreground App:", appProcess.processName));
                return false;
             }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While leaving activity or Home button clicked,

Activity`s lifecycle method, onPause() method used to call. If application need memory for other operation then moved to onStop() method.

Kindly let me know if i have cleared your question.

Thanks.