# Detect key home press from service

Tags: android

[image]
[image]

Hi i have broadcast application and I have a floating window

purpose: to view this window every activity I visit.

so my goal is that to minimize my floating window when I user press home button

SO my question is is there any way to detect if home is press?

if yes please guide me into it.

thanks in advance.

Pss.. I also tried to search it on this website but seems I haven't found a solution yet on it.

Note: it should be on service not in activity

Comment: According to me. You can't get the home key event from services. But you can get some Idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android/8883447#8883447).

Comment: bro did you see this  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()

Comment: @Vij it works but it also trigger whenever I start a new activity :( also I am handling a service not an activity