# React native handle Home button press in android?

Tags: android, react-native

Can I add some handle after user press Home button in android ?

Such as show modal ask user need to exit app or cancel.

I see this link [Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android) can helpful.

But I do not know how to apply that code to `MainActivity.java` of android in react-native.

`onUserLeaveHint` is work after app close but I need modal work before app close.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself. I open sourced my solution here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-home-pressed Let me know what you think