# Button listener in background to trigger activity

Tags: android, button, listener, assistant

Recently I've started to write my own assistant, but encountered with a problem. I need to listen Push to Talk (physical) button event even when my app is on background. I know button listeners are not available within Service's, but I wonder how come Google Assistant can be triggered when there is another app on foreground ? Does anyone know what is different on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is very possible to do it, IF you have chance to compile your own Android version. For reference you can try imitate [following class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/car-lib/src/android/car/input/CarInputHandlingService.java)  and implementations around it.

Although, this is not only implementation and change, it also requires changes in HAL layer.

Also I couldn't find how Google handles this. But my best guess would be either something like [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/car-lib/src/android/car/input/CarInputHandlingService.java) or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android).