# Xamarin.Forms ViewRenderer audio doesnt stop on homepage/backbutton

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-mediaplayer, viewrendering

I am new so excuse me if I dont ask a question right or post enough information.

I am new to creating mobile applications and i am using `Xamarin.Forms` to create a custom view.  with this view I am using an Android `ViewRenderer` to play audio/video with built in android `MediaPlayer/VideoView`.

pretty much the exact same thing as the android renderer posted and accepted as the answer for [Renderer I copied and is working](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40580/play-video-in-background-like-spotify-using-xamarin-forms-and-android-renderer)

My issue is when the video starts and you click the homepage/back button the audio continues playing for a few seconds and then stops.  I want to audio to stop immediately.

**Methods I have tried:**

In my `ViewRenderer` I have attempted to `override SurfaceDestroyed` to call `player.stop()`.  This has not worked, no errors or anything just audio continues like this code doesnt exist.  Audio stops after about 3-5 seconds.

In the `ViewRenderer` I have attempted to use the `Control.SystemUiVisibilityChange` event to call `player.stop()`.  No errors or anything.  Audio continues for 3-5 seconds.

I am unable to pass the `player` instance to the main activity `onPause()` method as I am to new to `Xamarin.Forms` and android `ViewRenderers` to understand how to. Possibly calling this `player.stop()` on the `onPause()` method will work but I cant find how to do this.  Can anyone assist? I have searched many forums for weeks and have finally given up to post a question.

Comment: Have you tried overriding onbackbuttonpressed() and ondisappearing() to then put player.stop() on that?

Comment: I did start to try that but was unable to get the proper override structure to override onbackbuttonpressed() from my viewrenderer.  

I will work on trying that tonight to see if that works.  When my app is interrupted (call / another app / minimized) is onbackbuttonpressed() called? 

I thought onPause() was called from the MainActivity when the home button was pressed. If thats the case how to I find the mediaplayer instance from MainActivity if its initiated and called by a viewrenderer?

Comment: I did try override OnDisappearing from the Xamarin.Forms application. In my view I made a method called "StopAction" and on my renderer im doing e.newelement.StopAction => () => player.pause();

On my ondisappearing I was calling "VideoView.StopAction()" and the video would not pause.  I would get a null error and then the application would do its normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

For back button, you simply need to override `OnBackButtonPressed` of your current `Xamarin.Forms`' page:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        //stop the videoview
        videoview.Stop();
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
   ...
}
```

For home button, I referred to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android) and made a Xamarin version of `HomeWatcher` out of Jack's answer:

```
public interface IOnHomePressedListener
{
    void OnHomePressed();
    void OnHomeLongPressed();
}

public class HomeWatcher
{
    static readonly String TAG = "hg";
    private Context mContext;
    private IntentFilter mFilter;
    private IOnHomePressedListener mListener;
    private InnerRecevier mRecevier;

    public HomeWatcher(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionCloseSystemDialogs);
    }

    public void SetOnHomePressedListener(IOnHomePressedListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;
        mRecevier = new InnerRecevier(mListener);
    }

    public void StartWatch()
    {
        if (mRecevier != null)
        {
            mContext.RegisterReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter);
        }
    }

    public void StopWatch()
    {
        if (mRecevier != null)
        {
            mContext.UnregisterReceiver(mRecevier);
        }
    }


    private class InnerRecevier : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        readonly String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
        readonly String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";
        readonly String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
        readonly String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";
        IOnHomePressedListener _listener;

        public InnerRecevier(IOnHomePressedListener listener)
        {
            _listener = listener;
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.Action;
            if (action.Equals(Intent.ActionCloseSystemDialogs))
            {
                String reason = intent.GetStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                if (reason != null)
                {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "action:" + action + ",reason:" + reason);
                    if (_listener != null)
                    {
                        if (reason.Equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY))
                        {
                            _listener.OnHomePressed();
                        }
                        else if (reason.Equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS))
                        {
                            _listener.OnHomeLongPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in the `VideoViewRenderer` ( `StartWatch()` when video start play, `StopWatch()` when the videoview is cleaned):

```
public class VideoViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoView, Android.Widget.VideoView>, ISurfaceHolderCallback,IOnHomePressedListener
{
    ...

    private MediaPlayer _player;

    private HomeWatcher _homeWatcher;



    public VideoViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _homeWatcher = new HomeWatcher(context);
        _homeWatcher.SetOnHomePressedListener(this);

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomVideoViewDemo.VideoView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        e.NewElement.CleanAction = new Action(() =>
        {
            #region Clean video player action (player no more used)

            if (_player == null)
                return;
            //stop watch home button
            _homeWatcher.StopWatch();


            _player.Release();

            #endregion
        });



        e.NewElement.PlayAction = new Action(() =>
        {
            #region Play video if it was stopped


            if (_player == null)
                return;
            //start watch home button
            _homeWatcher.StartWatch();
            if (!_player.IsPlaying)
            {
                _player.Start();
            }

            #endregion
        });

       ...
     }

  }
```

Comment: Elvis, Thank you.  I didnt get a change to work on my code last night I will attempt to do it tonight and let you know and accept the answer if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: So this did not work for me either.  It appears that on the first time im calling this.player.pause(); in my code its not registering.

If I hit pause then play then pause my mediaplayer pauses..... its a really weird issue.  I think my question has nothing to do with a home button reading.  Should I form a new question with code samples?

Comment: You need to provide your codes of implementation. You can form a new question, if you want.