# Android activities - mimic isolated application behavior (process every intent separately)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, back, android-launcher

I write an activity which I'd like to behave (in terms of instatiating it) similar to command-line tools such as, let's say, `sort` (imagine: sort = my_application, pipe "|" = intent_resolution)

In Android world it would be that every intent is processed by my activity, and I still can go back.

---

Use case is like that:
We have an Activity `com.A`.

1. User runs it from home screen:

`LAUNCHER/MAIN of com.A`
(screen Ax appears)

2. Home button is pressed.
3. Then user runs A with explicit intent

`am -n com/.A -e some_extra` (screen Ay appears - it's different because it depends on intent)

4. Home button again.
5. User runs A again (third time) from launcher icon:

`LAUNCHER/MAIN of com.A` (screen **Ay** appears, because Android 'thinks' that user wants previous activity. But **he'd like to see Ax** again - as a proper response for intent LAUNCHER/MAIN)

---

I can obtain such behaviour by setting `launchMode=singleTask`, so my every intent is processed by `onCreate` or `onNewIntent`. But in such case **I lose history**. So if A calls B and B calls A (A → B → A) I will lose first A. The same if A calls A (A → A) than I cannot go back.

---

Is this possible to set such a combination of `<activity>` manifest attributes or using other means to obtain that behaviour?

Note: if I change `LAUNCHER/MAIN` for any other intent it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that combination of

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
```

and default `launchMode` works more or less as I need. I still haven't tested it that deeply and don't expect it gonna work 100% precise but at the moment it works fine.

I also tried to [detect home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android)
and then finish activity manually, but apparently it's not very reliable neither.

---

Edit: Downside of this solution is that every time phone rings or you just lock your screen then the app with such manifest is destroyed.