# Capturing a hardware button press in a library

Tags: android

I didn't find an answer to this question, so here we go.
I have an android library that doesn't implement any View or android Application class, and I need to capture a hardware button press.

I couldn't override / implement any KeyEvent callback function.

Any idea on how can i do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can only capture the home button and recents button without a focusable overlay.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android) for an example of how to do that.

The only way to capture all events would be to use an Accessibility Service.

Comment: I need to catch an "extra" button, because it's a specific hardware that adds functionality. Android recognizes this button events but I couldn't catch it. I'll try your example as soon as I can, thank you.