# How to prevent click on Home button from going to home screen (springboard)?

Tags: java, android, homescreen, android-homebutton

My users require an alert in order to avoid leaving accidentally my app when clicking on Home button (otherwise, they loose their -long- work and have to restart it... Indeed, my AR app cannot recover its state at restart).

So, I want to display an alert asking if they really want to leave if they click on the home button.

I saw some posts explaining how to override the Home button in order to catch the click event.

Namely this one: [Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android) (use of 'HomeWatcher' or of 'onUserLeaveHint()')

Ok great, I catch the click event but as far as I can see, the app is left anyway and the user is sent to the home screen (springboard).

Is there any way to to what I want:

- catch the click event on Home button
- display an alert
- go home only if the users confirms that he wants to leave

Comment: There is no "springboard" on Android. That's iOS.

Answer (score 4):

No, for security reasons, there is no way of blocking the default behavior of home button.