# React native listening to app foreground or background switching in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a requirement of pausing video and some other actions to perform when user clicks on home button or switch to another app using swiper action. I looked at react-native AppState, but it is not calling the event listener when home button clicked on android for some devices. Is there any compatibility minimum version requirements for the react-native app state to work?

The code I tried is as below

```
useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
}, []);

const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: any) => {
    console.log(nextAppState);
};
```

The console is not printed when clicked on home button/Swiped to another app on some android devices. Is there anyway I can achieve this using react-native preferably without using any external libraries.

Comment: Okay, so you just want to detect is application is in background or in active state, right?

Comment: @aditya, Yes looking for a way to know the application state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android), you could easily write your own native module for React-Native https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46

Comment: Or you could google and find this react-native package - it may work, and if not it would give you a place to start for capturing the home button press https://github.com/evanjmg/react-native-home-pressed

Answer (score 3):

As for your requirement, in react-native, to detect is application is in foreground or in background, you don't need to add home-button listener, we can easily achieve this with the help of `AppState`, check below example,

```
_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: any) => {
    if (this.state.appState === "active" && nextAppState === "background") {

        // this condition calls when app goes in background mode
        // here you can detect application is in background, and you can pause your video

    } else if (this.state.appState === "background" && nextAppState === "active") {
    
        // this condition calls when app is in foreground mode
        // here you can detect application is in active state again, 
        // and if you want you can resume your video

    }
   this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
};
```

You also need to attach AppState listener to application to detect application states, for example,

```
componentDidMount() {
     AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
}
```

and detach app-state listener when application component unmount, for example,

```
componentWillUnmount {
     AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
}
```

Or if you are working with functional component you attach or detach app-state listener in useEffect, for example,

```
useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
       AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: I did tried that as I showed in my question but the problem is the app state listener is not invoked on some old phone when swiped to another app or when clicked on home button.

Comment: Okay, you edited question, that's fine. But can you add some brief about devices(software version and other) on which AppState listener is not working.