# How to use the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU while i click the image button in android

Tags: android, menu, imagebutton, keyevent

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MENU pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Here i want to use this functionality using image button inside my application

```
  if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "MENU pressed");
                return true;
        }
```

is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to open the menu on the click event of your ImageButton, You have to use

```
openOptionsmenu();
```

inside ImageButton's onClickListener.

```
 imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                openOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
```

Comment: do u want to open menu during the imageButton click or need to do something else? can you tell me that please

Comment: yes.i dont want to open menu but ,if i click the image button,menu button functionality will work without using openOptionsMenu...

Comment: Oh, if that's the case, you have to call the method what you have used in ur menu. If you try to get the key Code event of Menu button, it won't work as you expected. So simple call the method inside ImageButton's onClick event to do the task.

Comment: if using game application,firing while using menu button,instead of this ,i have to use image button

Comment: can we call this method inside onclick if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {}

Comment: But clicking on Image Button will not trigger  KeyEvent KEYCODE_MENU. How r u planning on doing that?

Answer (score 0):

**It is handled by framework itself and never delivered to applications.**

But you can achieve it using `Reflection`. See this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872330/3496570)