# KeyCode, KeyEvent Not working

Tags: android

How can i stop services which is running on background.
Is there any way to do it using Back and home button press

I have tried to do it using key events but still it's not working. Here you can check my code  below ...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {          
        stopBackgroundAudio();// background services 
        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {           
        stopBackgroundAudio();
        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)) {            
        stopBackgroundAudio();
        return true;
    }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Help me with this or suggest me other option to stop service?

Comment: These key are handled by Android OS. But you can use it using reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31872330/3496570

Answer (score 1):

Back and home don't use that API.  THe back key comes in via the backButtonPressed function, which you can override.  The home button doesn't come up ever-  your app just gets pushed to the background.

Also, if you want the audio to stop when you're put int he background, just stop it in onPause.

Comment: This would not solve issue since onPause is also called while moving from one activity to another

Comment: True, but he didn't specify he needed that.

Comment: Right my friend, but he clearly specified that he wants to stop service only on home press or back button.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
        stopBackgroundAudio();// background services 
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
         stopBackgroundAudio();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
       stopBackgroundAudio();
            return true;


        }

       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

i am not sure yours service is a bind  or unbind service, if it is unbind service than it may be a problem and also if it is a bind service than have a proper implementation!!

Comment: hey use return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); in place of return false; answer is updated