# Capturing Android's "multitasking" button

Tags: android, keyevent

I haven't been keeping up with Android phone evolution since I've gotten a (lame) WP8 work-phone. Apparently, the dedicated Menu key on newer devices is being phased out in favor of something called a Multitasking button.

*Example: Samsung Galaxy S5*
[image]

As the image points out, you can still use this button as a Menu button, but I'd like to call a function directly from a single press. Is there a `KeyEvent` constant that corresponds with this button?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a KeyEvent constant that corresponds with this button?

Yup!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH

Comment: Are you sure this is actually capturable? This comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579818/hw-to-capture-app-switch-key-using-onkeydown-in-android#comment10640004_8579910) suggests it isn't, and I don't have a device to test with.

Comment: Hm, I've never tried it, but after a bit of research it looks like it isn't possible. It looks like there's an API in Android L that allows you to lock the user into the app, though, which might accomplish what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039004/how-to-ignore-button-click-of-recent-activity-button-in-android-3-0