# How to override double click of power button or volume button in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, overriding, android-button

I am trying to create a simple Flashlight App

1. What I want is, whenever user presses KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN 2 times or single time, I want to switch on the FlashLight, or whenever user presses KEYCODE_POWER 2 times
2. It can be done from anywhere i.e., whether my app is opened or not , or whether screen is off or not ?

For Testing purposes, I am just showing a Toast notification, but I couldn't override KEYCODE_POWER , how to override KEYCODE_POWER ?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Power Down pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textview1.setText("Power Button Pressed");
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            //event.startTracking();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Up Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Volume Down pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: check out this post might get help [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682016/android-listen-for-power-key-press)

Comment: @Clairvoyant That was fine, its a type of trick I think, Anyways I'll try to make out something, from that link, it was helpful, Could you tell me anything about how I can do that irrespective of whether my app is on or off, means from anyscreen, if user presses volume up or down 2 times or 3 times, something should be done ?

Comment: make integer variables and increment them in keydown method for the desired condition and check if value is greater than equal to 2 if true then the button is pressed two times and then make the variable value again to zero so it will again increment to 2

Comment: @Clairvoyant OK, I get it, thank you, but my question is how to do the above you wrote, from anyscreen, i mean user should not run my app, something like background service like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brink.powerbuttonflashlight&hl=en

Comment: you cant handle the key event in service

Answer (score 0):

To access key press from any where even the phone is locked but not when screen off.

Create a class Myaccessibility then extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
Then override onKeyEvent in that class.

Register the service inthe Manifest
For mor information on how to create accessibility service

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service