# BroadcastReceiver - how to trigger service every time user ON/OFF screen

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

*Hello*

I want to check whether my service is running or not, if service is running, do nothing.

But if service is not running, restart the service.

So I do something like this.

`In Manifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name="com.varma.android.aws.receiver.Receiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`Receiver.java`

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("aws", "Received...");

    if(isMyServiceRunning(context)) {
        Log.v("aws", "Yeah, it's running, no need to restart service");
    }

    else {
        Log.v("aws", "Not running, restarting service");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Service.class);
        context.startService(intent1);
    }

}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (Service.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

**But nothing is happening when I ON/OFF screen**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478013/1677824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't register screen on/off broadcast through manifest file,tt doesn't work(need to explore why).
Register it in your main activity through code

```
    ifilter=new IntentFilter();
    ifilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    ifilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(new Receiver(), ifilter);
```

Till the time your activity remains in memory you will receive these broadcasts in your receiver, i have tested it and able to receive broadcasts.
However if your activity gets finished you won't receive these broadcasts. So registerting these broadcasts in some **LocalService in your app with START_STICKY** feature will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your service to stay up, you don't need to do this.  Just have onStartCommand return START_STICKY.  This will cause Android to restart any service it stops as soon as it has sufficient memory.

Comment: I have included it in `Service.java` but noting much happening