# broadcastreceiver not working,please take a look

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I know the solution might be somewhere, but I tried searching, but can't fix anything.
what is wrong? I don't get it.
this is what I have

```
 <receiver
      android:name="com.example.listeners.screenlistener"
      android:enabled="true" >
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
      </intent-filter> 
 </receiver>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Please be **much** more specific than "not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick stab at this, to receive the SCREEN_ON or other protected broadcasts, you have to register the receiver in code somewhere and not in the manifest.

Working example here:

[BroadcastReceiver for Screen On/Off not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161062/broadcastreceiver-for-screen-on-off-not-working)

Edit: I provided this answer as I remember trying something similar about a year ago when I was just learning Android. The question could certainly do with more clarification on what the user is trying/has tried to do.