# Android Screen/OtherApp listener

Tags: java, android, events, screen, listener

I just wondered if (app is closed) there is a way to get notified when:

1. The screen turns on/off,
2. Another app starts/was closed.

I already found some hacky ways that might work, but they dont seem to be quite confidential.
Some of them seem to only work on some phones. I am looking for "clean" way that works on all phones.

Why I would like to know that:

1. To track the time I am spending during the day on my phone,
2. To be able close the system alert window if a user opens another app.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wondered if (app is closed) there is a way to get notified when:

We'll see.

> (1.1) The screen turns on/off

Yes there is. Try using a **BroadcastReceiver**.

> (1.2) Another app starts/was closed.
>
> (2.1) To track the time I am spending during the day on my phone,
>
> (2.2) To be able close the system alert window if a user opens another app.

There's no way to do this UNLESS you're a root user. Each application has it's own working side.

Comment: Thanks :)<br>
I am doing it that way now <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161062/broadcastreceiver-for-screen-on-off-not-working