# How to stop sound after Screen Lock

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onpause, screen-lock

Hi I need to stop sound from mediaplayer on screen Lock As I am using

```
if(mp!= null && mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
  }
```

in onPause()  . But there is no result. So, How can I stop my media player sound after screen is locked.

To say exactly, I have 16 mp3 files, which will come in random.if a sound is playing and the screen is locked, present sound is Stopped and next one sound is playing.After screen is unlocked, it will works as proper & when the screen is locked , Again same is repeating on my Android 2.3.6 version mobile. How to overcome this.

Thank you.

Comment: Refer to this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off

Answer (score 2):

I have already faced with similar issue, the following code solved my problem:

```
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        PowerManager mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        if (!mPowerManager.isScreenOn()) 
             if (mp!= null && mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to handle it via Screen On & Off intents.

See the link below for details:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Answer (score 0):

> I think You need to set up your code to stop  sound in receiver of
>   Screen off

here is more detail about how to deal with screen lock receiver . http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/