# How to get broadcast for screen lock in android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, screen-off

How to get trigger that screen is locked or on in android??

i tried using SCREEN_OFF & SCREEN_ON action in broadcast receiver but it's not working.

```java
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("XYZ", "Screen ON/OFF");

    Toast.makeText(context, "screen",10000).show();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        .......
    }
}
```

in activity i have registered broadcast like-

screen is object of my broadcast receiver

```java
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
mContext.registerReceiver(screen, filter);
```

Comment: have you register your receiver in manifest or programatically??

Comment: where you are registering your broadcast receiver?

Comment: Check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off)

Comment: make 1 service and register boradcast receiver in service..and start service when mainActivity starts.By doing this your receiver will be fired on screen off or on @yuva

Comment: @yuvaツ  how u resolved your problem ?

Answer (score 10):

Call the `UpdateService.class` within your `MainActivity.class` .

`startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateService.class));`

**UpdateService.class**

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    public static int countOn = 0;
    public static int countOff = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
        Log.i("UpdateService", "Started");
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);
        mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        Log.i("onDestroy Reciever", "Called");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
        if (!screenOn) {
            Log.i("screenON", "Called");
            Log.i("viaService", "CountOn =" + countOn);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Awake", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i("screenOFF", "Called");
            Log.i("viaService", "CountOff =" + countOff);
        }


        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Receiver class**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
            // Log.i("via Receiver","Normal ScreenOFF" );
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER)) {

        }

        Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: the service will run continuously for checking screen on or off.i want to avoid that only.

Answer (score 4):

Hey try using dynamic calling of broadcast,I tried this it will surly work...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     //Create broadcast object
       BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        //When Event is published, onReceive method is called
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "MyReceiver");

                if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                    Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen ON");
                }
                else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                    Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen OFF");
                }

        }
    };

     @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
       registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
     }
    }
```

Comment: i'm not getting any error.but i can't see any log/ toast which i have mentioned in receiver

Comment: you have to make a service and try to call broadcast in that service.

Comment: but that service should run for long time.it's consuming battery for that i want to detect screen off & on.if screen is on then only i want to start my applications service