# Restart App when screen is locked

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android app and for security reasons it can never be left on while a user is not using it. How can I restart my app when the user locks the screen or it auto locks.

When the user unlocks the device is should be at the login activity.

Can I clear all tasks when the screen is locked. How is this done?

Update

I cannot finish() activities in the onPause as i use onPause for NFC foregroundDispatch so i need a different solution

Comment: On Pause override  is what will be triggered when the app is not visible

Comment: is OnPause called for other reasons because if i finish the activity and it is called else where then that would cause issues

Comment: ok so far that works nicely, i didn't realise you could have multiple activities be finished at the same time in this way, i am just reading the document on when onPause is called.

Comment: it does cause issue as i use onPause and onResume for NFC, i would need a different solution

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a broadcast receiver that listens for the broadcast action ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and set a state in your session to help your app to decide when the onResume calls start. (see [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)). Here is a link with someone asking how to implement this receiver (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899438/how-to-get-broadcast-for-screen-lock-in-android))