# Attaching code to user turning on screen

Tags: android, wakeup

I'm trying to work a piece of code that works so that when the user turns on the screen, an event or piece of code is called and ran. This needs to work when the screen goes to sleep as well and should have a cancel feature to stop this occuring at the users command. Could anyone suggest any ideas on how to code this in android

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: broadcast receiver for screen on and screen off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something **when your `Activity` become foreground or background** you can override `onWindowFocusChanged`,

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    if(hasFocus){
        //activity become foreground
    }
    else{
       //activity become background
    }
}
```

If you want to do something just based on screen state, regardless of your applications activity visible or not than you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` but still need a service or activity running on the background check out this question [android: broadcast receiver for screen on and screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off)