# Enable Keyguard without locking the screen immediately?

Tags: android, keyguard

In my app I disabled the visible keyguard screen with

```
if (mKkeyguardLock == null) {
    mKkeyguardLock = ((KeyguardManager)getSystemService("keyguard")).newKeyguardLock("tag");
}
mKkeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Then I reactivated the keyguard:

```
mKkeyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
mKkeyguardLock = null;
```

This works, but the lock gets visible then immediately. But it should be enabled but inactive. Difference: The app remains visible. Only if the user presses the power button briefly, the lockscreen gets visible. Do you have any idea how to reenable but not activate the keyguard?

I also tried:

```
Window wind = MyActivity.this.getWindow();
if (wind != null) {
    wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}
```

and reenabling

```
wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

This does not reactivate the keyguard at all.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to broadcast listener when screen is on or off. then you can moderate keyguard.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478013/3813997)

for example you want to disable keyguard. if screen is on, do nothing , but if screen is off then disable the keyguard .