# Android - Kill an app when screen turned off or screen times out

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to kill / fully close an app so it doesn’t run even in the background when I press the screen turn on/off button or if the screen times out. I couldn’t find a solution anywhere on the internet. Can you guys help me out with a code snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can refer this link to detect screen turn off
[Screen off Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477922/android-broadcast-receiver-for-screen-on-and-screen-off)  and for killing the app you can use below code

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if the screen is locked inside a service that runs in the background:

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
  getActivity().finish();
  System.exit(0);
} else {
 //it is not locked
}
```

then you simply kill the app if the screen is locked.
hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

To make activity like a toast (appear-and-go) add following code into manifest:

```
<activity   android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="YourActivityLabel"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```