# Intent filter of broadcast receiver for off screen registered manually but not working?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

According to this answer [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478013), I have registered a broadcast receiver for the device offscreen but the receiver not working I registered this MaintActivity and unregistered in onDestory() of service.
please correct me if anyone knows.

```
LockReciver lockReciver=new LockReciver();
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(lockReciver, screenStateFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add your receiver in the manifest file. If you are using the screen on/off intent filter for broadcast receiver then you have to register your receiver as you mention in your question but also add your receiver in the manifest file just like below.

```
<receiver
    android:name="YourReciverName">
</receiver>
```

and don't need to add an intent filter here because you manually register and unregister your receiver from the code, just add your receiver in the manifest file.

Comment: wow, work fine I forget the receiver tag in the manifest.Thanks