# Overriding the power button in Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app in which I need to do an action when the power button is pressed but unfortunately I cant handel the action of power button when it is pressed. I tried using the onKeyDown() and dispatchKeyEvent() methods but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone suggest me any other method or solution for this problem.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // The action I want to perform when power button is pressed.
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android

Comment: if you only worry about your own device and if it's rooted, you can modify the keyboard layout file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer and this can be done by using the AlarmManager with the PowerManager

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))) {

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TEST");
wakeLock.acquire();

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent inten = new Intent(context,NewActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, inten, 0);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,  100, pi);
}
}   

// Finish your WakeLock HERE. call this method after U put the activity in front or when u exit from the new activity.
public void finishWakeLocker(){
if (wakeLock != null) 
wakeLock.release();  
}
```

> Here first the screen goes off and then I'm waking it by using the AlarmManager. I couldn't stop the screen going to off state by overriding the Power button controls. I'm just waking up the device as soon as it goes to sleep state.

Comment: Brilliant. What exactly does the wakeLock do?

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, this is not possible, except perhaps via custom firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you intend to do, but you could use a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen for the `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF` or `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` which is sent when power button is pressed (and screen is on).

Unfortunately this intent will be sent when the screen times out too. But I think you can prevent the phone from being locked (while in an application) like this

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Comment: I tried using the BroadCastReceiver with the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF even this is not responding when the power button is pressed, but on the other hand it is working for the screen time out.

Comment: Using the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF I can do the actions before locking the screen but can't stop the screen being locked.

Comment: Yes, the intent is sent after the event has occurred. I don't think you can override the power buttons existing functionality.