# Stop the Screen Locking when power button is pressed

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding the power button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886466/overriding-the-power-button-in-android)

Is there any possible way I can stop the screen being locked when the power button is pressed.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent a user having control over their own phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop screen to get lock(short click), But you can get the event of long keypress of Power button

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        //dostuff
        return true;
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: FORTUNATELY you can't stop screen from locking. An app should never affect the basic functionality of a device. If an app did that to me it gets uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

you can't : http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/6904f14ffb3e6bb8?pli=1

Answer (score -1):

try this as per your Requirement,

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
    KeyguardLock lock;


    public void Disable_AutoLock() 
    {   

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);        
        lock.disableKeyguard();

    }

    public void Enable_AutoLock() 
    {
        lock.reenableKeyguard();

    }
```

Give permission in android manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```