# How to react to android power button properly

Tags: android, button, onkeydown, power-off

I want to make a walkie-talkie app using the power button as Push-to-talk.
Therefore i need to replace the button's behavoir to 
Using onKeyDown onKeyUp or OnKeyLongPressed() trigger events works to receive, but after thre trigger event is processed, screen goes off.

What i have found searching
[Overriding the power button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886466/overriding-the-power-button-in-android)
[How to hook into the Power button in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android)
doesn't help me since i can't get the Cyanogenmod to work on this phone.

Maybe you have some Idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The power button will trigger your app at any point while the screen is on? Or the power button will only trigger within your app while the screen is on? Should it respond when the screen is off? etc.

Comment: Btw, I'll say up front that I doubt it's possible, and it sounds like a bad idea from a UX point of view except in very specialized cases. When I press the power button, I want that thing to be off.

Comment: For the first step it should trigger my app only when it is active.

Comment: You mean I'm in the middle of an app, I press the power button and your app appears?! How do you turn the phone off?

Comment: Turn my app off, then go on as normal. I haven't thought deep on UX at the current situation. I just liked the idea of a similar behaviour like a 1990 walkie talkie with a speak-button on the side. Usage would be Push button and keep pressed: talk,  release button: listen again.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the behavior of the power button, except via your own custom ROM mod (e.g., CyanogenMod).