# Android - I want to detect power button clicks on Canvas 2.

Tags: key

I want to detect power button clicks for Micromax Canvas 2. I have used broadcase receiver for ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF. and inside onReceive Method i have written my code. For other devices its working fine, for Canvas 2 its showing Power off menu. is there any other way to detect the key press.

Comment: This cant be done through programming. Read this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886466/overriding-the-power-button-in-android

Comment: This cant be done.

More information here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button