# Disable the power button in activity

Tags: android, performance, android-button, android-hardware

I'm developing an app in which there is a requirement to not let the user to lock the screen or turn off the android device using power button,so I have to disable the power button and over ride the power button functionality, I have searched alot on internet as well but can't find anything.I have used these two pieces of code but still it did not work for me.

```
 @Override
      public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
              if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
                      Log.i("", "Dispath event power");
                      Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                      sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
                      return true;
              }

              return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
      }
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
      {
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
                // Back
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
            }

            else {
                // Return
```

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't deal with the Power event in any Android Apps. `Events of`Power Button`are handled in Framework level in Android architecture`. **You can't stop `framework` to dispatch events but accept its dispatch**. You can receive the result of event dispatch from framework but not block the process.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the user from controlling his phone,You could perhaps prevent the device from [sleeping or locking itself](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html).
Tapping into the power button,however, is possible as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365166/3396197)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. This link was helpful:
["Overriding The Power Button"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886466/overriding-the-power-button-in-android/)

My issues was keeping a camera app from being accidentally stopped, so my answer was slightly different than Bob's. I simplly recalled the existing event. So, in other words, this worked for my app: (put in BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

The snippet that is different for me is:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// POWER BUTTON - SHORT click
// We are moving from a SCREEN ON state to a SCREEN OFF State
//--------------------------------------------------------------
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
{
    wasScreenOn = false;
    if (cameraIsOn)
    {
        PowerManager newPM = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = newPM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TEST");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent ExistingIntent = intent;
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, ExistingIntent, 0);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 10, pi);
    }
        return; 
}
```

Still doing tests, but that seems to work for me. (I have to also monitor the camera record state because when the screen goes off, the camera stops. I restart it -- but of course, some video is going to be lost. It seems, tho, that without rooting the device, that is an impossible thing to stop from happening.)

On one hand, I understand why the power switch HAS to be able to be called to shut the device off. OTOH,it makes idiot proofing stuff (on a re-purposed device)  impossible.