# Android - Is it possible to prevent screen from turning off programatically if user presses power button?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing a mission-critical application for an Android Tablet.

I'd like to foolproof the application, specifically to prevent the user from shutting down the app or turning the screen off during some important processes, which take some time.

For preventing the user from exiting or hiding the app, there's [Lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode).

After searching on SO, I found that this is probably not possible [is not really possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button/10118001#10118001) - however that answer is from 2012 - Is this still the case?

Meanwhile, I did implement the workaround of turning requesting to turn the screen back on if the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` intent is detected, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29403924/4574731), but it's fairly ugly, and also the keyguard is sometimes disabled and sometimes not, I'm not sure why.

Here's my code:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Screen off was detected, requesting to turning the screen back on...")

                // Disable key lock, so keygoard will not be shown once the screen light back up
                val keyguardManager = getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
                keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this@MainActivity, null)

                // Ask to turn the screen back on - lifted from here
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143686/4574731

                // Ask device to keep screen awake
                val powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
                val wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP or PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
                    "rpicapp:turnScreenOnReciever"
                )
                wakeLock.acquire(10*1000L /* 10 seconds */)

                try {
                    // Broadcast the ACTION_SCREEN_ON intent after 10 milliseconds
                    val alarmMgr = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                    val screenOnIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON), 0)
                    alarmMgr[AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 10] = screenOnIntent
                } finally {
                    wakeLock.release()
                }

            }
        }
```

Is there a better workaround for this in 2021?

Thanks

Comment: If your tablet is Samsung Tablet you can use Samsung Knox to disable the button when needed. If the user will press the button he will get a Toast message saying "Security policy prevents the use of this key" or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer unfortunately: it's not possible unless the phone is rooted.

You could do what you want by getting only root permissions, however, users with rooted phones are very few nowadays .. but it always depends on your context. If you provide the tablet to run the application on, you could root it and use this to realize your functionality.