# Handle alert when shut down device android in rooted app

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, power-off

I want change this message "Your phone is shut down" that appear when shut down the device.[image]

Do you have any ideas?

My app download videos in the background, I must warn you not to switch off the device if the download is not yet finished, such as happens when you shut down Windows and is downloading updates.

Comment: Its a system triggered dialog so, we possibly cannot change it. Do you mind telling why this use-case arose?

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Yes, its not a nice UX to change these dialogs (even if possible at all). For your use-case, you need to handle these manually. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448304/handling-phone-shutdown-event-in-android) should help you in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

MainActivity.java I intercept the power off button and force close system dialog and create a View custom above it

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // Do something here...
        event.startTracking(); // Needed to track long presses

        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        mViewCustom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adriana take a look at [Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN), i am not sure if you can handle like you want.

Additionally this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826092/abort-a-shutdown-event-in-android-wait-for-an-activity-completed) is related to this.