# How to detect when power button is pressed in Broadcast Receiver class when Device Administrator permission is activated in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, device-admin

I am trying to detect when power button is pressed in BroadcastReceiver class, Actually I am implementing it when Device Administrator Permission is activated.
I have google so much but not able to find it.

In broadcast receiver class, when screen is ON and OFF then I am detecting it using this method

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) 
        {
          Log.v("Screen Off", "Screen OFF");

        }

        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) 
        {
          Log.v("Screen ON", "Screen ON");
               }
```

But I have to detect when power button is pressed only.
One thing, I want to make it clear there are many application which is performing this functionality, for example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.startv.gumrah .This is many using for SOS application like

> an emergency App that, at the click of the power button of your
>   smartphone 2 times consecutively begins sending out alert messages

Please help me how to detect when we press power button.

Comment: Cant you catch key events for that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180659/power-key-event-in-android May help you

Comment: @Charan Pai I have tried to implement key event but it throughs NPE

Comment: @Shweta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button look this
**also this** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/pNtN7xvaqNk

Comment: @Shweta NPE for what ?? paset the stack trace.. NPEs are easy to solve

Comment: if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
;
       }

Comment: event.getKeyCode()  is throughing null pointer exception

Comment: use `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER == keyCode` as in answer for that question in the link above.

Comment: @Shweta Have you found an answer? Can you share the details.

Comment: @Shweta Did you got the solution??