# How to disable shutdown and reboot from an app with system priviliges?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, shutdown, reboot, android-reboot

I am developing a System App (i.e. an app signed with the device manufacturer's key) for non-rooted devices.

I need to prevent the user from shutting-down or rebooting the device.

If necessary and possible, disabling the power button completely would be a solution, though all I require is to be able to prevent the shut-down dialogue which appears when the power button is held-down.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the `KeyEvent` for this action, which is `KEYCODE_POWER`. See this post:

[Power key event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180659/power-key-event-in-android)

The important thing here is after you handle the `KeyEvent` you need to return `true` to let the system know that it has been handled.

Comment: I've tried a half-dozen forms of this solution, and none worked on my device.