# How to handle Android power button events?

Tags: android

I want to create an Android application that is opened in background when the power button is pressed twice.

I want to know how can I handle power button and choose what happens when user press power button?

Just as we have in Safety Apps which sends SOS messages on certain number of power key presses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hook into the Power button in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android)

Comment: post what you tried already

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the following `permission` to your `manifest file`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
```

It has two methods `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyLongPress()` `@Override` these two methods for performing some actions.

Comment: is this still working on recent android? (4.4 to 5.1)
I tried on 5.1 but it does not work.