# Want to Access Power Button events in android

Tags: android, android-event

```
   i=0;
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("In Key Down Method." + event.getKeyCode());
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        i++;
        System.out.println("Power button pressed.");
        if (i == 2) {
            System.out.println("Power button pressed continuoulsy 3 times.");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Power button pressed " + i + " times.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Power button pressed continuoulsy " + i + " times.");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Power button pressed " + i + " times.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I am trying to access power button event using above code.Its working fine for Volume_Up and Volume_Down Key but not Working For Power/Lock Button.Why it happens?
Suggest Some Example or code.

Comment: But its also not working.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following permission to your manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />`

Comment: This permission is no longer available.
Its better to follow @Devendra Singh 's answer